# VMware Workstation Player bridged connection doesn't work

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

I tried to use bridged connection VMware and Virtualbox but doesn't work.I need a router ? or I need another wireless adapter?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue a little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brigde mode means that VM's network cart simulates connection to your real physical network. You may setup static IP, mask and gateway of your network or obtain them by dhcp (yes, you need router to configure your local network).